# Facebook API Open Graph custom stories shared between friends

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

SO! I made FB-app for custom stories. But now have some problem.
First person (blue underline) share one page via FB-app (custom story). It looks on his FB-profile like:

[image]

Than second person (red underline) - **his friend** - share **same page** with some tagged friend via FB-app (custom story). It looks on his FB-profile like:

[image]

It`s problem! It shows (mentions) profile owner name ( red line) and  his friend ( blue line)  which before (see 1 screen) also shared **same page** via **same  FB-app**. How I can prevent this FB-behaviour? Goal:  show only who shared (owner) without any mentions his friends which also shared same page via unified FB-app?

*I checked all app-settings, read tons of FB Open Graph docs ( it's terrible!). I stuck.*

Comment: _“How I can prevent this FB-behaviour?”_ – you can’t. If multiple people undertake the same action on the same object, then Facebook might show that in such an aggregated view – simply as to not clutter up people’s newsfeeds with lots of more or less identical posts. That is nothing you have any control over.

Comment: (And why does your question title say “Twitter API”?)

Comment: @CBroe Oo, yes.. Sorry, of course, Facebook API ( I was sleepy and tired when writting). "simply as to not clutter up people’s newsfeeds with lots of more or less identical posts" But it introduces misunderstanding, when people shares with tagged users ( like in my situation): one with somebody, one without. But FB combines all in single viewing.